# Make a circuit so that it heats water as rapidly as possible

Tags: thermodynamics, electric-circuits

To do this I understand that we need to create the greatest power.

What I don't understand is why would we need to use a parallel circuit instead of a series circuit to create the greater power?

Comment: Try adding a few elements in series and calculate the associated power. Next, add the same elements in parallel, and again calculate the power. How do the powers compare?

Comment: what are the independent variables in the experiment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your power supply.

The power $P$ through a circuit element is always given by
$$ P_\text{thing} = I_\text{thing}V_\text{thing} $$
where $I$ is the current through and $V$ the voltage drop across the thing that you're interested in.  If your circuit element obeys Ohm's Law
$$
V_\text{thing} = I_\text{thing} R_\text{thing}
$$
then you can write the power is
$$
P_\text{thing} = I_\text{thing}^2R_\text{thing} \quad\text{or}\quad P_\text{thing} = V_\text{thing}^2/R_\text{thing}.
$$

The thing that we're interested in here is our *power supply*: we want to build a circuit where as much of the power as possible flows into the water.  There are two possibilities:

- Our power supply might output a constant current, $I$.  In that case we'll get more power $P=I^2R$ if we connect the resistors in *series*, so that the *full current* from the supply flows through each resistor. We'd get less total power if we connect the resistors in parallel, so that only a small part of the current flows through each resistor. A set of resistors connected in series has an equivalent resistance $$R_\text{series} = R_1 + R_2 + \cdots$$ which is *larger* than any of the individual $R_i$, and a constant-current circuit uses more power $P=I^2 R$ for larger $R$.
- Our power supply might output a constant voltage, $V$. In that case we'll get more power $P=V^2/R$ if we connect the resistors in *parallel*, so that each resistor is across the *full voltage* of the power supply. We'd get less total power if we connect the resistors in series, so that each resistor sees only a small fraction of the voltage drop. A set of resistors in parallel has an equivalent resistance $$R_\text{parallel} = \left(\frac1{R_1} + \frac1{R_2} + \cdots\right)^{-1}$$ which is *smaller* than any of the individual resistances $R_i$, and a constant-voltage circuit uses more power $P=V^2/R$ for smaller $R$.

We happen to live in a world where constant-voltage power supplies (like batteries) are more common that constant-current power supplies (like those driven by photocurrents), so a parallel array of resistors is more likely to be a better heater than a series array.

Comment: I don't understand how if we used series with a power supply that outputted constant voltage we'd get less power as each resistor only sees a fraction of the voltage drop.

Comment: Suppose you have a 10V power supply and ten 100Ω resistors. If you connect them in series you have $R_\text{series} = 1000\,\Omega$ and the total power is $P = V^2/R_\text{series} = 0.1\,\mathrm{watt}$. If you connect them in parallel you have effective resistance $R_\text{parallel}=10\,\Omega$ and power $P=V^2/R_\text{parallel} = 10\,\mathrm{watt}$. In either case you can use Ohm's Law to find the power in each individual resistor.

Comment: right, even if I forget which one has greater resistance I can just make up numbers for the voltage, current/resistance and then figure out which one has the greater power.